# How to read mouse click event from X server

Tags: c, mouseevent, xlib

I want to log my mouse click positions. I have tried this;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


int working = 1;

void signal_callback_handler(int signum) {
    working = 0;
}

int main () {
    signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_callback_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_callback_handler);

    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    assert(d);

    XSelectInput(d, DefaultRootWindow(d), ButtonPressMask);
    while(working) {
        XEvent e;
        XNextEvent(d,&e);
        if (e.type == ButtonPress) {
            printf("%dx%d",e.xbutton.x,e.xbutton.y);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

But I am seeing this error:

```
X Error of failed request: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Major opcode of failed request: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
Serial number of failed request: 7
Current serial number in output stream: 7
```

What is wrong with my code, and how can I fix it?

**Update**

I have researched this a little bit more, and got some help from the folks in #xorg-dev. It seems like it is impossible to do with regular Xlib, because only one client can register for button press on a window. In this case, my WM already registered, therefore I get bad access. It seems like this can be done using X input extensions and by listening XI_RawButtonPress Event, which I am still trying to figure out how to do. Here is what I have so far;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XInput2.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <assert.h>

int working = 1;

void signal_callback_handler(int signum) {
    working = 0;
}

int main() {


    signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_callback_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_callback_handler);

    /* Connect to the X server */
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    assert(dpy);

    /* XInput Extension available? */
    int opcode, event, error;
    if (!XQueryExtension(dpy, "XInputExtension", &opcode, &event, &error)) {
        printf("X Input extension not available.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Which version of XI2? We support 2.0 */
    int major = 2, minor = 0;
    if (XIQueryVersion(dpy, &major, &minor) == BadRequest) {
        printf("XI2 not available. Server supports %d.%d\n", major, minor);
        return -1;
    }


    XIEventMask eventmask;

    unsigned char mask[1] = { 0 }; /* the actual mask */

    eventmask.deviceid = 2;
    eventmask.mask_len = sizeof(mask); /* always in bytes */
    eventmask.mask = mask;

    /* now set the mask */
    XISetMask(mask, XI_RawButtonPress);

    /* select on the window */
    XISelectEvents(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), &eventmask, 1);

    while(working) {
        XEvent ev;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
        if (ev.xcookie.type == GenericEvent &&
                ev.xcookie.extension == opcode &&
                XGetEventData(dpy, &ev.xcookie))
        {
            switch(ev.xcookie.evtype)
            {
                case XI_RawButtonPress:
                    printf("RawButtonPress");
                    break;
            }
        }
        XFreeEventData(dpy, &ev.xcookie);
    }
}
```

However, I get this error;

```
X Error of failed request:  XI_BadDevice (invalid Device parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  46 ()
  Device id in failed request: 0xad
  Serial number of failed request:  15
  Current serial number in output stream:  15
```

**Update 2**

I have tried to do this with ButtonRelaseEvent, but I am not getting any event. XNextEvent blocks forever, no matter where I click/relase button. Here are the codes;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>


int working = 1;

void signal_callback_handler(int signum) {
    working = 0;
}

int main () {
    signal(SIGINT, signal_callback_handler);
    signal(SIGTSTP, signal_callback_handler);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_callback_handler);

    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    assert(d);

    XSelectInput(d,DefaultRootWindow(d), ButtonReleaseMask);

    while(working) {
        XEvent e;
        XNextEvent(d, &e);
    printf("Something Occured");
        if (e.type == ButtonRelease) {
            printf("%dx%d",e.xbutton.x,e.xbutton.y);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `XWindowEvent` instead of `XNextEvent`.

For example to grab mouse you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/cursorfont.h>

int main(){
    Display* display;
    int screen_num;
    Screen *screen;
    Window root_win;
    XEvent report;
    XButtonEvent *xb = (XButtonEvent *)&report;
    int i;
    Cursor cursor;
    display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    if (display == NULL){
        perror("Cannot connect to X server");
        exit (-1);
    }
    screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
    screen = XScreenOfDisplay(display, screen_num);
    root_win = RootWindow(display, XScreenNumberOfScreen(screen));
    cursor = XCreateFontCursor(display, XC_crosshair);
    i = XGrabPointer(display, root_win, False,
                ButtonReleaseMask | ButtonPressMask|Button1MotionMask, GrabModeSync,
                GrabModeAsync, root_win, cursor, CurrentTime);
    if(i != GrabSuccess){
        perror("Can't grab the mouse");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        XAllowEvents(display, SyncPointer, CurrentTime);
        XWindowEvent(display, root_win, ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask, &report);
        switch(report.type){
            case ButtonPress:
                printf("Press @ (%d, %d)\n", xb->x_root, xb->y_root);
            break;
            case ButtonRelease:
                printf("Release @ (%d, %d)\n", xb->x_root, xb->y_root);
            break;
        }
    }
    XFlush(display);
    XUngrabServer(display);
    XCloseDisplay( display );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide simplified example? I have started to learn Xlib 1 hour ago, and I can't follow all the things that happen in that example.

Comment: Can't we do this without grabbing the mouse? I want this program run in background while I do my usual stuff.

Comment: Maybe, but I've try different variants and all they have failed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from x11 protocol spec:

> Multiple clients can select input on the same window; their
>   event-masks are disjoint. When an event is generated, it will be
>   reported to all interested clients. However, only one client at a time
>   can select for SubstructureRedirect, only one client at a time can
>   select for ResizeRedirect, and only one client at a time can select
>   for ButtonPress. An attempt to violate these restrictions results in
>   an Access error.

However, it is allowed for multiple clients to select ButtonRelease event - I just checked with two clients and both receive events.

Comment: Just tried your example - it actually receives ButtonRelease events, but they are buffered. Try to select `ButtonReleaseMask|PointerMotionMask` and move mouse for some time. Note that on most desktops/WMs root window is usually obscured but some other fullscreen window. Use `Xephyr` or `Xnest` to test