# How do I intercept mouse buttons without blocking in xlib c

Tags: c, mouse, xlib

I'm trying to intercept mouse buttons using xlib c (specificly 4 and 5). I want to this without blocking and prefrebly without external libraries except from xlib.

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561267/how-to-read-mouse-click-event-from-x-server)'s answer and it works but blocks input (I can't click on any other windows).

This is my attempt but it pauses at `XNextEvent` forever without giving any output

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

static Display *display;

int main(void) {

    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XSelectInput(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), ButtonReleaseMask);
    
    XEvent event;
    while (True) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        printf("Something happened: %s\n", event.type);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: offload to another thread

Comment: By block I mean blocking the mouse input for any other window @yano

Comment: Have you tried `XPeekEvent`?